# Antispam thtottler

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am working on creating a telegram bot, I want to make an anti-spam system, that is, when a person presses a button too many times, the bot will freeze for him for a certain number of seconds, it is possible to write a message about blocking. People in other matters do not help me.

```
import {
    bot
} from '../token.js';

import {
    keyboardMain
} from '../keyboards/keyboardsMain.js';

export function commands() {
    bot.on('message', msg => {
        const text = msg.text;
        const chatId = msg.chat.id;

        if (text === '/start') {
           return bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'hello', keyboardMain);
        }

        return bot.sendMessage(chatId, 'error');
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you use [telegraf](https://www.npmjs.com/package/telegraf) as telegram module ? If yes, you can [kick](https://telegraf.js.org/classes/Telegram.html#kickChatMember) users from channels or groups.

Comment: node-telegram-bot-api

Answer (score 0):

here is a little piece that i made for you :)
you can apply it to anything ^_^

```js
var tps = 0;
var allowpassage = false;
var detectspamon = document;
c = function() {
    setTimeout(()=>{
        console.log("got clicks:",tps);
        if (tps==0) {console.log("no clicking detected");}
        else if (tps==1) {console.log("success");allowpassage=true;}
        else {console.log("too many clicks per second");}
        tps=0;
        console.log("setting clicks to 0");
    },500);
}

detectspamon.onclick = () => {tps++;console.log(tps);c(tps);}
```

Comment: How should it be applied? I'm new at this.

Comment: well you see where it says "success"? thats where you put a function that fires when you want to send the message

and where it says too many clicks per second thats where you put a function that fires when you want them to be frozen.

and you see the detectspamon? you make that hold the button that you want them to click on